# Two actions for one route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have such problem:
I have two models: **User** and **Page**.
**Users** and **Pages** have field *url*.
So I have routes
`get ':url' => 'users#show'` and `get ':url' => 'pages#show'`
How should I redirect from this route to one of the actions *users#show* or *pages#show*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a proxy action first, an action that checks if the url is a user or a page searching the db and then call the real action

something like

```
get 'users/:url', to: 'users#show', as: 'show_user'
get 'pages/:url', to: 'pages#show', as: 'show_page'
get ':url', to: 'application#user_or_page'
```

on ApplicationController

```
def user_or_page
  if u = User.find_by_permalink(params[:url])
    redirect_to show_user_path(u)
  elsif p = Page.find_by_permalink(params[:url])
    redirect_to show_page_path(p)
  else
    # do something with an invalid url
  end
end
```

I guess you can render some template instead of the redirects if you want that, but I would use a redirect

Comment: I know this solution but I need links without *users/* and *pages/*.
I want to move this parts of code to two controllers.

Comment: as I said at the end, you can render templates instead of doing a redirect, just do 'render template: "users/show"'

Comment: Thank you. I'll do this way

Comment: be sure to do all the before_filters/actions and instantiate all the variables that you need for your template

Answer (score 0):

There is a one to one relationship between a url and an action. So /url can either to to user#show OR pages#show, but not both.

Sounds like you may want two separate routes one for /users/url and /pages/url, in which case you may want routes like...

```
match 'users/url' => 'users#show'
match 'page/url' => 'pages#show'
```

Comment: This is definitely the better way to structure your routes.