# Rails routing: two actions for one route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-4.1

**Hello**
I have two user roles: *User* and *Operator*
So I have two namespaced controllers:

```
/users/pages_controller.rb
```

and

```
/operator/pages_controller.rb
```

So problem is routing:

I want it to render action in user's namespace.

If `user.operator?` action should be `operator/pages#index` and if `user.user?` action should be `user/pages#index`

Some time ago I asked question [Two actions for one route in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337648/two-actions-for-one-route-in-rails) but the answers aren't what I want.

**Also in one project I faced a bug(or feature): if action raises error rails render next controller for this pattern.**

Maybe someone knows about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions but it depends of what you want:

- you can use only one namespace and do your if in the controller, depends of the complexity or your app
- you can have 2 completely distincts namespace, but you risk to have a lot of code in common, also depends of your app
- you can have 2 distincts namespace, and share partials for the views and use module concern for share code in controller

Comment: I want two have two distinct namespaces but want to have the same route for them.  
I hope there is a solution based on raising errors

Comment: Why do you want the same url? If you do two things different you must have two url or you use the same controller and you do your if in the controller like i said. It's like you wanna have two house in the same address, it's not logic.

Comment: In my app only registered users have access to site. 
There are operators and basic users.
But they operate same entities. So I want to make same routes for them

Comment: So use the same controller. Like i said, you can either decide to manage each role (user, operator) separately with two namespace or you can do the access control in the controller of the resource you want to manage (with the same url but not in the namespace user). Also you can always do in other way but it's bad practice.

Comment: They have rather different logic.
Ok, maybe there will be two separate namespaces

Comment: I have encountered this problem many times, and it just a choice of the architecture of your app, a choice you have to make.